# How to configure the Composer to always download the latest version?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

My composer is downloading version 5.4.36. How to configure the Composer to always download the latest version.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Execute `php -v`.

Comment: PHP 5.6.31 (cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5.4 is the latest version with PHP 5.6 support.

Laravel 5.5 requires PHP 7.0, Laravel 5.6 requires PHP 7.1.